# Select same nodes which exists consecutively

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have XML and I want to select same nodes which appear consecutively.

```
<main>
    <topic1>
        <ntb>1</ntb>
        <ifs>2</ifs>
        <jst>3</jst>
        <ifs>4</ifs>
    </topic1>
    <topic2>
        <ifs>1</ifs>
        <ntb>2</ntb>
        <jst>3</jst>
        <ifs>4</ifs>
        <ifs>5</ifs>
    </topic2>
</main>
```

I tried below code:

```
<xsl:template match="topic2/ifs">
    <count_node>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </count_node>
</xsl:template>
```

When I tried the above code all `<ifs>` tags are selected.

I want to select the last two `<ifs>` tags inside `<topic2>` tag using XPath since they are consecutive

expected output :

```
<count_node>
    <ifs>4</ifs>
    <ifs>5</ifs>
</count_node>
```

Comment: Please provide what you've tried first. People will appreciate that more.

Comment: @Kainix i added the tried code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Any luck with `//*[preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())]` (untested)

Comment: @supputuri i think it is not working

Comment: Can you show an example of your expected output ?

Comment: @Vebbie I added my expected output

Comment: @ShehanLakshmen Check the xpath that I provided in the answer and let me know.

Comment: Is "consecutive" based on the position in the child sequence of `topic2`? Or based on the value (e.g. `4`, `5`)? What would happen with a `<topic2><ifs>1</ifs><ifs>3</ifs><foo/><ifs>4</ifs><ifs>5</ifs><foo/><ifs>6</ifs><ifs>7</ifs></topic2>`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen not based on value. I want to get the output as I mentioned in my problem

Comment: Elaborate your test cases, that helps people to give more generic answer.

Comment: Is consecutive a condition here? Or do you just want to copy the last two?

Comment: Which XSLT version do you use or can you use? In XSLT 2 and later this seems a job for `roup-adjacent` : `<xsl:template match="topic2"><xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::ifs)"><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[current-grouping-key() and tail(current-group())]"/></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yeah there is consecutive a condition here

Comment: @MartinHonnen i am using xslt 2.

Comment: It looks like you want to group adjacent elements by name... Use [Martin Honnen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016539/11102282) changing the grouping key to `name()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath to get the 2nd node with the same name consecutively.

```
//*[local-name()=name(following-sibling::*)]/following-sibling::*
```

You can use either name or local-name.

```
//*[name()=name(following::*)]/following-sibling::*
```

Edit:

Here is the xpath to select all the elements who are consecutive and have same tag name (works even if you have more than 2 consecutive elements with the same tag)

```
//*[name()=name(following-sibling::*[1])]|//*[name()=name(preceding-sibling::*[1])]
```

FYI: I have not hardcoded the tag name so it will pick any tag which are consecutive, if you are looking for specific tag please update the `*` with the tag name.

Edit: xpath used by OP.

```
//ifs[following-sibling::*[1][self::ifs] or preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ifs]]
```

Comment: I added my expected output. Can u edit the answer as my output. because when i use your xpath it is not working

Comment: Updated the answer please check and let me know.

Comment: Not sure why the answer was downvoted, when the OP updated the question after posting the answer.  Now the answer is updated based on the latest changes to the question.

Comment: @ShehanLakshmen were you able to get the nodes using the above xpath?

Comment: I used `ifs[following-sibling::*[1][self::ifs] or preceding-sibling::*[1][self::ifs]]` as Xpath

Comment: Ok, the xpath I provided will identify any consecutive tags, added the xpath that  you used to the answer too. If you feel like the issue is resolved. Please accept the answer by clicking on the  check mark below the down vote button and feel freee to up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <count_node>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </count_node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topic2/ifs[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::ifs] or following-sibling::node()[1][self::ifs]]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See the demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfD/1

**Note:** The above solution will populate all consecutive `<ifs>` nodes in `<topic2>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use XSLT 2 or later you can write a template for `topic2` elements that finds and wraps groups of at least two `ifs` child elements with

```
  <xsl:template match="topic2">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::ifs)">
          <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[2]">
              <count_node>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </count_node>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Complete example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiF, uses Saxon 9.8 so is XSLT 3 but above template uses only features already available in XSLT 2.